# Pandoc loses title and other metadata converting from docx to markdown

Tags: markdown, docx, pandoc

Convert the following markdown file to docx using `pandoc ex.md -o ex.docx`:

```
---
title: 'My beautiful title'
author: 'Joe Myself'
date: '2019-03-12'
...

Bla, bla, bla.
```

Now convert the resulting `ex.docx` back to markdown using `pandoc ex.docx -o ex2.md`. I expect `ex2.md` be similar to the input `ex.md`, instead the metadata block disappears.

I tried to specify from/to types plus/minus extension `yaml_metadata_block` or `pandoc_title_block` but nothing changes.
Looking at the markdown template I see it starts with `$titleblock$`, but how to convert the three metadata to a titleblock?

Looking at the AST with `pandoc ex.docx -t json` I see that title,  author and date are indeed present in `ex.docx`. What I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: Try adding the `--standalone` (short: `-s`) command line option.

Comment: Perfect! It solves my problem. I have only to pipeline the output to `sed` to get rid of `[]{#xxxx .anchor}` in the title.

Comment: In the real use case, obviously.

Comment: [Issue #1893](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1893#issuecomment-70892873) has a better solution to get rid of the title anchor.

Comment: -s didn't work for me. i have titles in docx but it all gets stripped in markdown. It should have # or ##

Comment: @chovy Try to put the text at the beginning into a file `z.md` then `pandoc z.md -o z.docx` and final `pandoc -s z.docx -o z1.md` you will see `z.md` and `z1.md` are identical. Or share a docx that show the problem.

Comment: https://file.io/ifWOakK3Q0pU here is the file.

Comment: Well, opened in Word and re-saved as `ex.docx`, then `pandoc -s ex.docx -o ex.md` show all headers correctly.

Comment: Looking at the internal structure of the two DOCX files (the original one and the re-saved one), besides different IDs, they have very different content in the `docProps` subdirectory. Is your file generated by some sort of tool and not World itself?